# FFMPEG request is slow

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video

I need to concatenate images to a video. Images contain black and white pixels, but I need to save quality of them as much as possible with saving space of disk. So, I don't need to use .mov.

And after that I'm going to load the video to a video hosting.

I'm running this command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -framerate 30 -pattern_type sequence -start_number 00000 -i "E:\Work\git_repos\projects\filestovideosconverter\target\resultImages202303261305\Our Wedding.7z.009-i%5d-d2.png" -c:v libx264 -movflags +faststar -crf 18 -pix_fmt gray -preset slow "E:\Work\git_repos\projects\filestovideosconverter\target\resultVideos202303261505\Our Wedding.7z.009-i5-d2.mp4"
```

It takes too much time.

Could you please help me to improve it?

UPD:

There are ~300k png images in a folder. They have 720p(1280x720) resolution.

My hardware: ryzen 3600, rtx 3080, 32gb ram, sata HDD with images

It takes ~2h 40m to create a video from the images. So, encoding speed is about 31 fps.

Comment: What is "too much time"? Whar format and size/resolution are the photos? What are your computer's hardware details? Encoding video isn't really fast unless you have specialized or very modern hardware.

Comment: And are you having the system extract these photos from inside a 7zip file? Have you tried extracting the archive and allowing ffmpeg to work on uncompressed files?

Comment: Images: 1280 x 720. Hardware: ryzen 3600, rtx 3080, 32gb ram. PNG images are in a folder, not in a zip. There are ~300k of them. Time: ~2h 40m

Comment: so, it encodes ~31 frames per second

Comment: 300k pictures in under 3 hours? Is there a benchmark you think your computer should be meeting? Are you seeking general advice on how to make this more efficient, or do you know things should be faster, and if so, why?

Comment: I've written a program that writes the images. It transforms bits of files to images. And there is a duplicate factor that makes 4 pixels per 1 bit. It takes less amount of time and less resources than encoding video from them. So, it's strange. I'm trying to optimize this request if it's possible.

Comment: Resizing/scaling images is quite a bit different than encoding them from static images to video.

Comment: It makes images from scratch, bit by bit, pixel by pixel, it's not about resazing or scaling...

Comment: If it's impossible to optimize it then I will try something else. Anyway, thank you for help